# Spark: how to change datarframe Array[String] to RDD[Array[String]]

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I have transactions as a DataFrame `array<string>`:

```
transactions: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [collect_set(b): array<string>]
```

I want to change it to `RDD[Array[string]]`, but when I am changing it to `RDD`, it's getting changed to `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]`:

```
val sam: RDD[Array[String]] = transactions.rdd
<console>:42: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]]
       val sam: RDD[Array[String]] = transactions.rdd
```

Answer (score 3):

`transactions.rdd` will return `RDD[Row]`, as it is in message.

You can manually convert Row to Array:

```
val sam = transactions.rdd.map(x => x.getList(0).toArray.map(_.toString))
```

More Spark 2.0 style it would be:

```
val sam = transactions.select("columnName").as[Array[String]].rdd
```

Replace columnName with proper column name from DataFrame - probably you should rename `collect_set(b)` to more user-friendly name

Answer (score 1):

Dataframe is actually a array[Row] so whenever you run collect on a dataframe it will create a array[Row] and when you are converting it RDD it becomes a RDD[Row].

So if you want RDD[Array[String]] you can do it this way:

```
val sam = transactions.rdd.map(x => x.toString().stripPrefix("[").stripSuffix("]").split(fieldSeperator))
```

Comment: Why parsing String if you can have pure object code? And `Dataframe is actually a array[Row]` is false, DataFrame is much more than just array

Comment: Yes Dataframe is much more than that but the basic unit of a dataframe is Row.

Comment: Still, parsing String sounds wrong. What if you will have "," in one of the strings? It will broke your code

Comment: ya that one thing we need to keep in mind but it will give the desired output and your solution is giving type cast exception.